# Is there a way to assign a variable in SPSS (x <- "string value") for use in multible syntax locations?

Tags: variables, syntax, spss

I have an SPSS syntax that I use often that has a couple of text strings that occur in several places. Is there a method of assigning the string to a variable in order to avoid changing the string in several locations? (analogous to the "X <-" in R )

```
x <- "repeated string example"
syntax object 1 = X.
...
syntax object n = X.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simplest use for SPSS macro language. For example:

```
* first you define the macro .
define !MyString () "repeated string example" !enddefine.
define !AnotherString () "ample" !enddefine.

* now you can use it in the syntax as in the following examples.
string SomeStringVar (a30).
compute SomeStringVar = !MyString.
compute MyIndex=char.index(!MyString, !AnotherString).
if someVar=!MyString cond=1.
```